# NumberPicker with arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, numberpicker, android-number-picker

I am trying to add a list of data within a numberpicker. I am using the library of: https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker for the numberpicker.

**This is how it appears in my app:**

[image: Image NumberPicker]

*As you can see it appears with [ ] at its sides and separated by a comma, how can I eliminate that? I guess that's the problem.*

I'm getting the information from the FIREBASE database.

**My code:**

```
IList = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Information").child( uploads.getIdPost() )
        .child("CBS1");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        IList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            IList.add(snapshot.getKey());

            String[] data = {String.valueOf( IList )};
            numberPicker.setMinValue(data.length);
            numberPicker.setMaxValue(data.length);
            numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(data);
            numberPicker.setValue(data.length);
            numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
String[] data = {String.valueOf( IList )};
```

`String.valueOf( IList )` will return a string whose value `[CB, CC]`. That why you see it on the NumberPicker UI.

**Solution:** Convert string arraylist to string array.

```
IList.add(snapshot.getKey());

// Convert string arraylist to string array.
String[] data = new String[list.size()];
data = list.toArray(data);

// Set minValue is 1 instead of data.length
numberPicker.setMinValue(1); 
numberPicker.setMaxValue(data.length);
numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(data);
numberPicker.setValue(data.length);
numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
```

**Update:** I think here is what you mean

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        IList.clear();

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            IList.add(snapshot.getKey());
        }

        // Convert string arraylist to string array.
        String[] data = new String[IList.size()];
        data = IList.toArray(data);

        numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(data.length - 1);
        numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(data);
        numberPicker.setValue(0);
        numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, what do you mean when you refer to "list"? Because if in both of them it says "list" I put "IList" it throws me this error:
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length = 1; index = 1
         at com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker.ensureCachedScrollSelectorValue (NumberPicker.java:2030)
         at com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker.initializeSelectorWheelIndices (NumberPicker.java:1815)
         at com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker.setMaxValue (NumberPicker.java:1528)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the following code:

```
String[] data = {String.valueOf( IList )};
```

where [String.valueOf](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) return the string representation representation of the `IList` Object.

You need to use something like [toArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])).